# How can I make a sliding dialog like Instagram?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog, instagram

How can I make a sliding dialog like Instagram?

Is there a specific class for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/develop/android/components/sheets-bottom).

Have a look at [this article about Android Bottom Sheets](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/android-bottom-sheet-5b64ddb3c02d).

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot :)